# Executing method on completion of two AsyncTasks

Tags: android

I have two `AsyncTasks` that run simultaneously when my app opens.

I have a method that I want to execute when BOTH tasks are done.

What is the best way to structure my activity to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take two flags for both the asynctask and in their respective onPostExecute set true to these flags and in OnPostExecute of both the asynctask check whether both the flags are set to true or not.If both flags are set true then execute your method otherwise doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself:

I created a `boolean isReady` field on my activity.

When either of the classes finish, they check the flag. If its false, they set it true. If its true, they run the method.